# React-router: how to obtain a reference to the router in a rendered component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React-router is rendering my component 'App'. (This is version 1.0.0 of react-router).

I need to get a reference to the router from inside 'App'. Is this possible?

The reason that I need to do this is because 'App' is rendering Breadcrumbs - which is an instance of react-breadcrumbs v. 1.0.2 - and react-breadcrumbs expects the router to be on this.content. (It looks like react-breadcrumbs is expecting Router to have done this). Anyhow; I've figured out how I can set context from App (using childContextTypes and getChildContext) but I can't see how I can get a reference to the router in the component it is rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contexts (a currently undocumented feature of React, but one that seems likely to stay for the time being):

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'App',
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.propTypes.func
  },
  render: function() {
    var { router } = this.context;

    // Do things with the router. Ex: getting a parameter
    var userId = router.getCurrentParams().userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: As of react-router 1.x this is no longer valid. router components can access this with this.props.params.state, other components apparently has no access to params

Answer (score 0):

You can add Router.History mixin to your App and then access the routes through this.props.routes.

Here is an example:

```
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");
var Breadcrumb = require("react-breadcrumbs");

var App = React.createClass({
   mixins: [
      Router.History
   ],

   render: function () {
      "use strict";

      return (
      <div>
          <Breadcrumb routes={this.props.routes}></Breadcrumb>
          <div>
              {this.props.children}
          </div>
      </div>);
   }
});

module.exports = App;
```